# Angular can not find the injector modulerr error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector, angular-module

here is my code:

I Have no idea where the error should be. i just received this error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=studentfeedback&p1=….c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)

I delete everything I added that day but i didn't change anything.
only if i fully cleared my html and angular the error is gone :p. so I have no clue where to  find the error. I hope somebody can help me. thanks

```js
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('studentfeedback', ['ngAnimate']);

  app.factory('Global', function(){
    
      var user = {};
      user.loggedin = false;
      user.achternaam;
      user.voornaam;
      user.vakken = [];
      user.periodecodes = [];
             
      return user;
  })
  /*
  app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var loggedin = false;

        return {
            getloggedin: function () {
                return loggedin;
            },
            setloggedin: function(value) {
                loggedin = value;
            }
        };
  });
  */
      
  app.controller('LoginController', [ '$http', '$scope','$timeout',  'Global', function($http, $scope , $timeout,  Global ){

    this.panelToggle = true; //true= login / false = register
    this.loggedin = Global.loggedin;

    //console.log("user:0110495-12, pass:LV ");
      
    this.checklogin = function(){
        var logincontroller = this;      
    
      //studentid           0110495-12 initials LV
       
        $http.jsonp("http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/stud.php?studentid="+ this.username+ "&initials="+ this.passwoord +"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"
      /* , {apikey:"test", params:{
         studentid : $scope.username ,
         initials : $scope.passwoord
         }}*/
                    
        ).success( function(data){
        
            
            if (data.state == "Success") {
                
                $(".formdiv").addClass("vanish");
                $timeout(function(){  logincontroller.loggedin = true; Global.loggedin=true;}, 500).then( $("h2").addClass("slidein") ); 
                $("body").addClass("whitebackground");
                Global.achternaam = data.student.achternaam;
                Global.voornaam = data.student.voornaam;   
                
                for(vak in  data.courses){
                    
                   for (code in Global.periodecodes ) {
                      
                       if(data.courses[vak].periodecode == Global.periodecodes[code]){
                      
                           Global.vakken.push(data.courses[vak]);
                       }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
                console.log(data.courses);
                console.log(Global.vakken);
               
                
                            
            }else{
                
              $(".loginform").addClass("shake");
                $timeout(function(){   $(".loginform").removeClass("shake"); }, 500);               
            } 
           
        });
          
        
    };
    
    
}]);
  app.controller('TimeController', [ '$http', '$scope','$timeout', 'Global',function($http, $scope , $timeout ,  Global){
     
      $scope.week;
      $scope.date;
      $scope.periodenaam = [];
      $scope.periodecode = [];

      
       $http.jsonp("http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/week.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success( function(data){
       
           //WEEK
             $scope.week = data.weeknr;
            console.log("week="+ $scope.week);
           
           //DATUM                                                                                                         
            this.year = data.date.year;
            this.month = data.date.month;
            this.day = data.date.day; 
                                                                                                                      
            if(this.month < 10){
                this.month = "0"+this.month;
            } 
            if(this.day < 10){
                this.day = "0"+this.day;
            }
           
            $scope.date = this.year+"-"+this.month +"-"+this.day;                                                                                                
            console.log("date="+ $scope.date);  
                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
       });
      
            
      $http.jsonp(" http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/periode.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success( function(data){
            

            for(periode in data.periods){
              
         
                
                if( $scope.date > data.periods[periode].start.full && $scope.date < data.periods[periode].eind.full)  {
                    
                    Global.periodecodes.push(data.periods[periode].periodecode); 
                    //$scope.periodenaam.push(data.periods[periode].periodenaam); 
                    
                }else{
                    //not right period
                }
                
            }
            
           
             console.log("alle periodecodes = "+ Global.periodecodes);
             //console.log("alle periodenamen = "+  $scope.periodenaam);
          
        }); 
     

}]);
    
  app.controller('UserController', [ '$http', '$scope','$timeout', 'Global', '$rootElement',function($http, $scope , $timeout ,  Global, $rootElement){
      
    

        this.data = Global;
        this.savepunten = function(){     
 
        };
      
}])();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="studentfeedback">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Student Feedback</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen|Lobster|Nunito|Asap|Merriweather+Sans|Pacifico|Righteous|Comfortaa|Fredoka+One|Amaranth|Gloria+Hallelujah|Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

  </head>
  <body >
<div class="formdiv" ng-controller="LoginController as Login"  ng-hide="Login.loggedin">
     
     <img class="owl"  src="img/ow2l.png" alt="owl" />
       <img class="owl2" src="img/owl3.png" alt="owl" />
      <form name="loginform" class="loginform"  ng-submit="loginform.$valid && Login.checklogin()" novalidate>
       
        <h1>Student Feedback</h1>


        <div class="login" ng-show="Login.panelToggle"  >
          <a class="logintab active" href="" >Login</a>
          <a class="registreertab "   href="" ng-click="Login.panelToggle = !Login.panelToggle">Registreer</a>
          <label for="username">Studenten nummer</label>
          <input type="input" name="username" id="username" value="0110495-12" placeholder="0086868-53"  ng-model="Login.username" required>
          <label for="passwoord">initialen</label>
          <input type="input" name="passwoord" id="passwoord" placeholder="BD"  ng-model="Login.passwoord" required>
          <a href="" class="passlink">Passwoord vergeten?</a>
          <input class="loginbutton" type="submit" name="login" class="preload" value="Login" >


        </div>

        <div class="register" ng-show="!Login.panelToggle">
          <a class="logintab2" href="" ng-click="Login.panelToggle = !Login.panelToggle" >Login</a>
          <a class="registreertab2 active"   href="">Registreer</a>
          <label for="studentennummer">Studentennummer</label>
          <input type="input" name="studentennummer" id="studentennummer">
          <label for="kdgmail">kdgmail</label>
          <input type="input" name="kdgmail" id="kdgmail">

          <label for="username">gebruikersnaam</label>
          <input type="input" name="username" id="username">
          <label for="password">passwoord</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
          <input type="submit" name="registreer" class="preload" value="Registreer">
        </div>

      </form>
      </div>
 .     
      <div class="studentpanel"  ng-controller="UserController as User" ng-show="User.data.loggedin">
    
       
      <header class="clearfix">
          <h2 class="s">{{User.data.voornaam +" "+ User.data.achternaam}} </h2>
          <div class="weekdiv"  ng-controller="TimeController as Time">
            
              <div class="activeweek">
               <a href="#" id="prevweek"></a>
               <h4 >WEEK {{week}}</h4> 
               </div>           
              
          </div> 
       </header>  
        <div class="vakkendiv clearfix">
        <form method="post" ng-submit="Login.savepunten()" >
         <div class="vakken" ng-repeat="vak in User.data.vakken"  >
             
                <p>{{vak.vaknaam}}</p>
                <input class="punt" type="text">
                <img class="underline" src="img/underline.png" alt="underline">
             
         </div>
         <input type="submit" name="oplsaan" value="Opslaan">
         </form>
        </div> 
        

      </div>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.spriteOnHover-0.2.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your javascript file

```js
  var app = angular.module('studentfeedback', ['ngAnimate']);

  app.factory('Global', function(){
    
      var user = {};
      user.loggedin = false;
      user.achternaam;
      user.voornaam;
      user.vakken = [];
      user.periodecodes = [];
             
      return user;
  })
  /*
  app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var loggedin = false;

        return {
            getloggedin: function () {
                return loggedin;
            },
            setloggedin: function(value) {
                loggedin = value;
            }
        };
  });
  */
      
  app.controller('LoginController', [ '$http', '$scope','$timeout',  'Global', function($http, $scope , $timeout,  Global ){

    this.panelToggle = true; //true= login / false = register
    this.loggedin = Global.loggedin;

    //console.log("user:0110495-12, pass:LV ");
      
    this.checklogin = function(){
        var logincontroller = this;      
    
      //studentid           0110495-12 initials LV
       
        $http.jsonp("http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/stud.php?studentid="+ this.username+ "&initials="+ this.passwoord +"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"
      /* , {apikey:"test", params:{
         studentid : $scope.username ,
         initials : $scope.passwoord
         }}*/
                    
        ).success( function(data){
        
            
            if (data.state == "Success") {
                
                $(".formdiv").addClass("vanish");
                $timeout(function(){  logincontroller.loggedin = true; Global.loggedin=true;}, 500).then( $("h2").addClass("slidein") ); 
                $("body").addClass("whitebackground");
                Global.achternaam = data.student.achternaam;
                Global.voornaam = data.student.voornaam;   
                
                for(vak in  data.courses){
                    
                   for (code in Global.periodecodes ) {
                      
                       if(data.courses[vak].periodecode == Global.periodecodes[code]){
                      
                           Global.vakken.push(data.courses[vak]);
                       }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
                console.log(data.courses);
                console.log(Global.vakken);
               
                
                            
            }else{
                
              $(".loginform").addClass("shake");
                $timeout(function(){   $(".loginform").removeClass("shake"); }, 500);               
            } 
           
        });
          
        
    };
    
    
}]);
  app.controller('TimeController', [ '$http', '$scope','$timeout', 'Global',function($http, $scope , $timeout ,  Global){
     
      $scope.week;
      $scope.date;
      $scope.periodenaam = [];
      $scope.periodecode = [];

      
       $http.jsonp("http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/week.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success( function(data){
       
           //WEEK
             $scope.week = data.weeknr;
            console.log("week="+ $scope.week);
           
           //DATUM                                                                                                         
            this.year = data.date.year;
            this.month = data.date.month;
            this.day = data.date.day; 
                                                                                                                      
            if(this.month < 10){
                this.month = "0"+this.month;
            } 
            if(this.day < 10){
                this.day = "0"+this.day;
            }
           
            $scope.date = this.year+"-"+this.month +"-"+this.day;                                                                                                
            console.log("date="+ $scope.date);  
                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
       });
      
            
      $http.jsonp(" http://multimediatechnology.be/workload/periode.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success( function(data){
            

            for(periode in data.periods){
              
         
                
                if( $scope.date > data.periods[periode].start.full && $scope.date < data.periods[periode].eind.full)  {
                    
                    Global.periodecodes.push(data.periods[periode].periodecode); 
                    //$scope.periodenaam.push(data.periods[periode].periodenaam); 
                    
                }else{
                    //not right period
                }
                
            }
            
           
             console.log("alle periodecodes = "+ Global.periodecodes);
             //console.log("alle periodenamen = "+  $scope.periodenaam);
          
        }); 
     

}]);
    
  app.controller('UserController', [ '$http', '$scope','$timeout', 'Global', '$rootElement',function($http, $scope , $timeout ,  Global, $rootElement){
      
    

        this.data = Global;
        this.savepunten = function(){     
 
        };
      
}]);
```

```css
body{

  background-color:#d8d8d8 ;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.ease{
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease ; /* property duration timing-function delay */
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease ;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease ;
    transition: all 2s ease ;
}
.preload{
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}
.loginform{
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.formdiv{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

}



h1{
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.registreertab, .logintab , .logintab2 , .registreertab2{
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(42, 42, 42);
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
 transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
.active{
    color:  rgb(49, 49, 49);
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(42, 42, 42);
}


.loginhover {
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0px 0px 0px rgb(42, 42, 42);
    color: white;


}
.registreerhover{
     box-shadow: inset 200px 0px 0px 0px white;
     color:  rgb(49, 49, 49);

}

.loginhover2 {
    box-shadow: inset -200px 0px 0px 0px rgb(42, 42, 42);
    color: white;


}
.registreerhover2{
     box-shadow: inset -200px 0px 0px 0px white;
     color:  rgb(49, 49, 49);

}



label{
    margin-left: 10%;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}
input{
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    transition: border 0.4s;
    border: none;
}

 input:not(:last-child){
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.loginbutton{
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;

 /* transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay]; */
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease ;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease;
}
.loginbutton:hover{
  background-color: rgb(165, 255, 165);
  color: green;
}
 input.ng-invalid{
  outline-color: #FA787E;
  border: 1px solid #FA787E;
}
 input.ng-valid{
  outline-color: #78FA89;
  border: 1px solid #78FA89;
}
.passlink{
  display: inline-block;;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: white;
}
.owl{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: 240px;
    width: 150px;
    animation-name: OwlSearchingForYou;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.owl2{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150px;
    animation-name: OwlSearchingForYou2;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}



@keyframes OwlSearchingForYou {
     0%,35%, 53% {transform: translateX(0);}
    40%, 50%{transform: translateX(130px);}
}
@keyframes OwlSearchingForYou2 {
     0%,82%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
    87%, 97%{transform: translateX(-110px);}
}


@keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 50%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}
    30%, 70% {transform: translateX(10px);}
}

.shake {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    animation-name: shake;

}

@keyframes vanish {
    0% {transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;}
      
    100% {transform: scale(1.15); opacity: 0;}
}
.vanish {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    animation-name: vanish;

}

/*USER INTERFACE*/


h2 {

    color: white;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    float: left;
    height: 130px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    background-image: url(img/paperstroke3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

    
 

 
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% {transform: translateX(-100%); }
      
    100% {transform: translateX(0px); }
}
.slidein {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    animation-name: slidein;

}

@keyframes whitebackground {
    0% { background-image:url(img/flatcolor.jpg) ;}
      
    100% {background-image:url(img/table.jpg);}
}
.whitebackground {

     animation-name: whitebackground;
   

}

.weekdiv{
  float: right;
    width: 50%;;
    
}

h3, h4{
   
    font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    margin: 0px;    
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
h4, .activeweek a{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
h4{
    font-size: 4vw;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;    
    width: 18vw;
    
}
.activeweek{
    height: 10vw;   
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-image: url(img/week.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


#prevweek{
    width: 24.1666666666%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 83.854166666666%;
    background: url(img/spritesheetprevweek.png) ;
   
    background-size: 1500%;
}




.vakkendiv{
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;

}
.vakken{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url(img/yellow-sticky-note.png);
    background-size: cover;
     
  
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: all  1s ease ;
    -moz-transition: all  1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all  1s ease;
    -o-transition: all  1s ease;
    transition: all  1s ease;

    
}
.vakken.ng-enter{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all
}
.vakken.ng-enter-stagger{
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
    
    -webkit- transition-duration: 0s;
    -moz- transition-duration: 0s;
    -ms- transition-duration: 0s;
    -o- transition-duration: 0s;
     transition-duration: 0s;
}
.vakken.ng-enter-active{
    opacity: 1;
}

.vakken p {
    text-align: center;
    height: 25%;
   
}
input.punt{
     margin: auto;
    height: 45%;
    width: 85%;    
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    
}
.underline{
    width: 70%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

/*CLEARFIX*/
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="studentfeedback">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Student Feedback</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen|Lobster|Nunito|Asap|Merriweather+Sans|Pacifico|Righteous|Comfortaa|Fredoka+One|Amaranth|Gloria+Hallelujah|Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">

  </head>
  <body >
<div class="formdiv" ng-controller="LoginController as Login"  ng-hide="Login.loggedin">
     
     <img class="owl"  src="img/ow2l.png" alt="owl" />
       <img class="owl2" src="img/owl3.png" alt="owl" />
      <form name="loginform" class="loginform"  ng-submit="loginform.$valid && Login.checklogin()" novalidate>
       
        <h1>Student Feedback</h1>


        <div class="login" ng-show="Login.panelToggle"  >
          <a class="logintab active" href="" >Login</a>
          <a class="registreertab "   href="" ng-click="Login.panelToggle = !Login.panelToggle">Registreer</a>
          <label for="username">Studenten nummer</label>
          <input type="input" name="username" id="username" value="0110495-12" placeholder="0086868-53"  ng-model="Login.username" required>
          <label for="passwoord">initialen</label>
          <input type="input" name="passwoord" id="passwoord" placeholder="BD"  ng-model="Login.passwoord" required>
          <a href="" class="passlink">Passwoord vergeten?</a>
          <input class="loginbutton" type="submit" name="login" class="preload" value="Login" >


        </div>

        <div class="register" ng-show="!Login.panelToggle">
          <a class="logintab2" href="" ng-click="Login.panelToggle = !Login.panelToggle" >Login</a>
          <a class="registreertab2 active"   href="">Registreer</a>
          <label for="studentennummer">Studentennummer</label>
          <input type="input" name="studentennummer" id="studentennummer">
          <label for="kdgmail">kdgmail</label>
          <input type="input" name="kdgmail" id="kdgmail">

          <label for="username">gebruikersnaam</label>
          <input type="input" name="username" id="username">
          <label for="password">passwoord</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
          <input type="submit" name="registreer" class="preload" value="Registreer">
        </div>

      </form>
      </div>
 .     
      <div class="studentpanel"  ng-controller="UserController as User" ng-show="User.data.loggedin">
    
       
      <header class="clearfix">
          <h2 class="s">{{User.data.voornaam +" "+ User.data.achternaam}} </h2>
          <div class="weekdiv"  ng-controller="TimeController as Time">
            
              <div class="activeweek">
               <a href="#" id="prevweek"></a>
               <h4 >WEEK {{week}}</h4> 
               </div>           
              
          </div> 
       </header>  
        <div class="vakkendiv clearfix">
        <form method="post" ng-submit="Login.savepunten()" >
         <div class="vakken" ng-repeat="vak in User.data.vakken"  >
             
                <p>{{vak.vaknaam}}</p>
                <input class="punt" type="text">
                <img class="underline" src="img/underline.png" alt="underline">
             
         </div>
         <input type="submit" name="oplsaan" value="Opslaan">
         </form>
        </div> 
        

      </div>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.spriteOnHover-0.2.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah thank you so much!
such tiny detail, must have got there by autocompleting.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's and issue with }])(); in the javascript file